# Racket output to XML file

Tags: xml, racket

I have a list of pair, like this:

```
((IDENTIFRIAR . str) (SYMBOL . =) (STRING-CONSTANT .  Hello world! ) (BOOLEAN-CONSTANT . true))
```

And I want to generate and output it as xml, like:

```
<elements>
    <IDENTIFRIAR>str<IDENTIFRIAR/>
    <SYMBOL>=<SYMBOL/>
    <STRING-CONSTANT> Hello world!<STRING-CONSTANT/>
    <BOOLEAN-CONSTANT>true<BOOLEAN-CONSTANT/>
<elements/>
```

How can I do it? I found myself looking at some long documentation of XML and xexpr and not understanding anything about how I can actually create, append and change XML entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's clean up your input. You had e.g.:

```
'(STRING-CONSTANT . Hello world!)
```

which is invalid.

Instead let's make an association list where the values are
strings, and use that as the input:

```
(define alist '((IDENTIFRIAR . "str")
                (SYMBOL . "=")
                (STRING-CONSTANT . "Hello world!" )
                (BOOLEAN-CONSTANT . "true")))
```

Let's transform that to an [x-expr](http://docs.racket-lang.org/xml/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._xml%2Fprivate%2Fxexpr-core..rkt%29._xexpr~3f%29%29), which is a way of representing
XML as an s-expression.

```
(define xexprs (for/list ([a (in-list alist)])
                 (match-define (cons k v) a)
                 `(,k () ,v)))
;; =>
;; '((IDENTIFRIAR () "str")
;;   (SYMBOL () "=")
;;   (STRING-CONSTANT () "Hello world!")
;;   (BOOLEAN-CONSTANT () "true"))
```

Now let's convert that using [xexpr->string](http://docs.racket-lang.org/xml/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._xml%2Fmain..rkt%29._xexpr-~3estring%29%29) from Racket's xml collection.

```
(require xml)
(xexpr->string `(elements () ,@xexprs))
;; =>
;; "<elements><IDENTIFRIAR>str</IDENTIFRIAR><SYMBOL>=</SYMBOL><STRING-CONSTANT>Hello world!</STRING-CONSTANT><BOOLEAN-CONSTANT>true</BOOLEAN-CONSTANT></elements>"
```

If you want indenting, then instead:

```
(display-xml/content (xexpr->xml `(elements () ,@xexprs)))
```

which displays:

```
<elements>
  <IDENTIFRIAR>
    str
  </IDENTIFRIAR>
  <SYMBOL>
    =
  </SYMBOL>
  <STRING-CONSTANT>
    Hello world!
  </STRING-CONSTANT>
  <BOOLEAN-CONSTANT>
    true
  </BOOLEAN-CONSTANT>
</elements>
```